# MySQL: Show specific records from table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I have tables with following structure:

**table1**

```
| ID1 | NAME | GROUP_ID |
-------------------------
|   1 |  AAA |      101 |
|   2 |  A_A |      101 |
|   3 |  BBB |        0 |
|   4 |  CCC |      103 |
|   5 |  C_C |      103 |
|   6 |  DDD |        0 |
|   7 |  EEE |        0 |
|   8 |  FFF |        0 |
|   9 |  GGG |        0 |
|   10|  HHH |      104 |
|   11|  H_H |      104 |
```

**table2**

```
| ID2 | NAME |
--------------
|   1 |  AAA |
|   2 |  BBB |
|   3 |  C_C |
```

**groups**

```
| GROUP_ID | NAME |
-------------------
|      101 |  AAA |
|      101 |  A_A |
|      103 |  CCC |
|      103 |  C_C |
|      104 |  HHH |
|      104 |  H_H |
```

'table1' is a table with all elements. At this table have duplicate records founded by criteria and this elements inserted in table 'groups'. At table2 have elements who matched with elements from table1.

I want to show all records from table1 who not in table2. If element from table2 is in table groups don't show all elements from this groups in result table. At this case the elements are AAA/A_A (group_id 101) and CCC/C_C(group_id 103)

**RESULT TABLE**

```
| ID1 | NAME | GROUP_ID |
-------------------------
|   6 |  DDD |        0 |
|   7 |  EEE |        0 |
|   8 |  FFF |        0 |
|   9 |  GGG |        0 |
|   10|  HHH |      104 |
|   11|  H_H |      104 |
```

The elements with names A_A and C_C not in RESULT TABLE because this items are duplicates.

I tried this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70253/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will display all the elements from `table1` that are not in `table2` by name, and 
also will filter out all the entries that are having the same id as a `group` entry that are present in `table2` (duplicates in your case).

```
select t1.* from table1 t1 left join groups g on t1.name=g.name 
left join table2 t2 on t2.name=t1.name
where (g.group_id is null or g.group_id not in (SELECT gg.group_id FROM TABLE2 t2 inner join groups gg on gg.name=t2.name))
and t2.id2 is null;
```

See your [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/427bf/15) updated.

Comment: The SQL fidle not include records in table groups sorry. This is correctly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70253/3

Answer (score 2):

How about:

For used groups:

```
select * from table1
where NAME not in (SELECT distinct(name) FROM TABLE2)
```

For all groups, regardless of use:

```
select * from table1
where NAME not in (SELECT distinct(name) FROM groups)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83b7c/45